# Assign column value based on the percentage of rows

Tags: sql, db2

In DB2 is there a way to assign a column value based on the first x%, then y% and remaining z% of rows?

I've tried using row_number() function but no luck!

Example below
Assuming that the below example count(id) is already arranged in descending order
Input:

```
ID   count(id)
5       10 
3        8
1        5
4        3
2        1
```

Output:
First 30% rows of the above input should be assigned code H, last 30% of the rows will have code L and remaining will have code M. If 30% of rows evaluates to decimal then round up-to 0 decimal place.

```
ID     code
5       H
3       H
1       M
4       L
2       L
```

Comment: Show us the code where you have used row_number().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with t(ID, count_id) as (values
  (5, 10)
, (3, 8)
, (1, 5)
, (4, 3)
, (2, 1)
)
select t.*
, case 
    when pst <=30 then 'H'
    when pst <=70 then 'M'
    else 'L'
  end as code
from 
(
  select t.*
  , rownumber() over (order by count_id desc) as rn
  , 100*rownumber() over (order by count_id desc)/nullif(count(1) over(), 0) as pst
  from t
) t;
```

The result is:

```
ID COUNT_ID RN PST CODE
-- -------- -- --- ----
 5       10  1  20 H
 3        8  2  40 M
 1        5  3  60 M
 4        3  4  80 L
 2        1  5 100 L
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.id,
       (case ntile(3) over (order by count(id) desc) 
            when 1 then 'H'
            when 2 then 'M'
            when 3 then 'L'
        end) as grp
from t
group by t.id;
```

This puts them into equal sized groups.

For 30-40-30% split with your conditions, you have to be more careful:

```
select t.id,
       (case when (seqnum - 1.0) < 0.3 * cnt then 'H'
             when (seqnum + 1.0) > 0.7 * cnt then 'L'
             else 'M'
        end) as grp
from (select t.id,
             count(*) as cnt,
             count(*) over () as num_ids,
             row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by t.id
     ) t
```